# (Pre-calc w/ Algebra) RREF for 3x3 Matrices

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus

I don't have much trouble putting a 2x2 matrix into reduced row echelon form, but I keep screwing up 3x3 matrices. 
EX from the current problem:

| 2 -17 11|

|-1  11 -7|

| 0   3  -2|

My issue is that I'll make the first numbers in rows 1, 2, and 3...1, 0, and 0 respectively but when I try to add and subtract rows, I lose my 1 in the first row and the issue continues when moving to the right.

**My question: Is there a certain order that works best when reducing these numbers? maybe doing all zeros first? all ones first?**

We've already moved on to inverse matrices which I'm understanding but can't do well in without knowing RREF haha.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an order.

Get a $1$ in the first column on the main diagonal if possible. Then use that $1$ to reduce all other entries in that column to $0$.

Then move to the next column and repeat, always getting the $1$ first and then using that $1$ to get $0$ in the other entries in that column.

Answer (score 1):

You should perform row operations with a goal in mind.

The first goal could be to make the first column $(1,0,0)^T$, once you achieve that, once you achieve that, if you perform $R_1+cR_j$ wouldn't affect the the $1$ in the first row since $$R_{11}+cR_{j1}=1+c(0)=1$$

Also, you should not have operatins of the form of $R_j + cR_1$ because that would introduce a non-zero element in first element of row $j$.

Your goal should be to find the pivot elements.

For beginners: To perform Gauss-Jordan Elimination:

- Swap the rows so that all rows with all zero entries are on the bottom
- Swap the rows so that the row with the largest, leftmost nonzero entry is on top.
- Multiply the top row by a scalar so that top row's leading entry becomes $1$.
- Add/subtract multiples of the top row to the other rows so that all other entries in the column containing the top row's leading entry are all zero.
- Repeat steps $2$-$4$ for the next leftmost nonzero entry until all the leading entries are 1.
- Swap the rows so that the leading entry of each nonzero row is to the right of the leading entry of the row above it.

Reference can be found [here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/statprogram/node/155).